# Trying to use leaflet map in Maui Blazor App but keep getting errors

Tags: c#, .net-core, leaflet, blazor, maui

I am very new to Maui blazor. I am trying to have a leaflet map in one of my component but get getting the error:

```
    Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: 'Could not find 'initMap' ('initMap' was undefined).
Error: Could not find 'initMap' ('initMap' was undefined).
    at https://0.0.0.0/_framework/blazor.webview.js:1:328
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

my component code(Map.razor)

```
@using Microsoft.JSInterop;
@inject IJSRuntime JS
@page "/map"

@using System.Threading.Tasks;

<div id="map" style="height: 500px;"></div>

@code {
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        try
        {   
            if (firstRender)
            {
                await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("initMap");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

}
```

The index.html script.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover" />
    <title>MauiLeaflet</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="MauiLeaflet.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="~/leaflet-map.js"></script>
</head>
```

my initMap function()

```
function initMap() {
    const map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        maxZoom: 18,
    }).addTo(map);
}
```

[image]
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to define `initMap` as a window function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `InitMap` as a window function or put it into it's own libary.

```
var MAP = {};
MAP.InitMap = () =>
{
  // do work
}
```

And call it like so

```
 await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("MAP.initMap");
```

Answer (score 1):

To help you debug you can use the [browser developer tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/developer-tools?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=android), it will make your life easier. In your case you will probably see that the `leaflet-map.js` is not imported.

Files imported from `index.html` should be in the `wwwwroot` folder, so you should move `leaflet-map.js` to `wwwroot/js/leaflet-map.js` and update the `index.html` file :

```
<script src="js/leaflet-map.js"></script>
```

Also generally you should include scripts at the end of `index.html` to be sure the HTML is initialized then the js run (or use [defer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer)).